# Preventing coordinate system from rotation while using SVG?

Tags: html, svg

Learning SVG for the first time, I came across `<defs>`, `<g>` and `<use>`. I noticed that whenever elements are grouped using `<g>` and then used using `<use>`, if rotation is performed, it is applied to the whole co-ordinate system. Say for example, if rotation by `90` degrees is performed on `<use xlink:href="#point" x="105" y="-105" transform="rotate(90 50,50)"/>` and then `x="100"`, the svg image moves along Y-axis. This creates confusion dealing with many images. Are there any techniques to avoid OR improvise this?

```html
 <svg width="500" height="400">
  <defs>
  <g id="point">
        <rect rx="4" ry="4" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="black"></rect>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="black"/>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" fill="white"/>
      </g>
</defs>
  <use xlink:href="#point" x="0" y="0" transform="rotate(270 50,50)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#point" x="0" y="-105" transform="rotate(180 50,50)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#point" x="105" y="0" transform="rotate(0 50,50)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#point" x="105" y="-105" transform="rotate(90 50,50)"/>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the nature of the beast. The concept of transformations goes even beyond being *applied to the whole co-ordinate system*. By doing a transformation you establish a new coordinate system for the element and its descendants. Check the [SVG 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace) for further details:

> ### 7.4 Coordinate system transformations
>
> A new user space (i.e., a new current coordinate system) can be
>   established by specifying transformations in the form of a ‘transform’
>   attribute on a container element or graphics element

Furthermore, the new coordinate system will be [established before](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) any other processing of the element takes place:

> The ‘transform’ attribute is applied to an element before processing
>   any other coordinate or length values supplied for that element.

That means all coordinates and lengths of the transformed element or its descendants will refer to this new coordinate system. It's the built-in mechanism in svg and, as far as i know, there is no way around it.

In my experience getting used to it might be a little hard at the beginning but once you get a grasp of it, it will make most things whole a lot easier. There is an excellent and very comprehensive 3-part series of blog post by Sara Soueidan which might help:

> #### Understanding SVG Coordinate Systems and Transformations
>
> - [(Part 1)](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) — The viewport, `viewBox`, and `preserveAspectRatio`
> - [(Part 2)](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-transformations/) — The `transform` Attribute
> - [(Part 3)](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/nesting-svgs/) — Establishing New Viewports